# I am new to Teradata and DB2 . I have to extract and load DB2 tables into files in teradata server and then load files to Teradata tables

Tags: sh

I am new to Teradata and DB2 . I have to extract and load DB2 tables into files in teradata server and then load files to Teradata tables. Can anyone help me with the detailed steps as I have not done data migration before.

I am not sure on which utility to use